# Cassandra: QueryBuilder.update with the list of UDTs

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0

We have a table where two columns are:

```
user_assignments      frozen<list<shift_user_assignment>>,
user_offers           frozen<list<shift_user_assignment>>,
```

and `shift_user_assignment` is

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS shift_user_assignment (
 id  timeuuid,
 note varchar,
 breaks frozen<list<shift_break>>)
```

I have DB entity POJO called `shift` with these two properties (other properties ignored).

```
@Column("user_assignments")
private List<UserAssignment> userAssignments;

@Column("user_offers")
private List<UserAssignment> userOffers;
```

I try to update `user_assignments` and `user_offers` using QueryBuilder.

```
Update update = QueryBuilder.update(ShiftById.TABLE_NAME);
    update.with(QueryBuilder.set("user_assignments", shift.getUserAssignments()))
           .and(QueryBuilder.set("user_offers", shift.getUserOffers()))
          .where(QueryBuilder.eq("company_id", companyId))
            .and(QueryBuilder.eq("id", shift.getId()));
cassandraTemplate.execute(update)
```

but I receive

```
org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraTypeMismatchException: Value 0 of type class java.util.ArrayList does not correspond to any CQL3 type; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value 0 of type class java.util.ArrayList does not correspond to any CQL3 type
at org.springframework.cassandra.support.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:84) ~[spring-cql-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(CqlTemplate.java:946) ~[spring-cql-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlTemplate.java:930) ~[spring-cql-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlTemplate.java:912) ~[spring-cql-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:278) ~[spring-cql-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:559) ~[spring-cql-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.execute(CqlTemplate.java:1333) ~[spring-cql-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

No issues if I store the entity using Spring Data Cassandra.
Any clue what/where/how should I map to be able to update these two columns with QueryBuilder?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's really hard to help if you aren't adding more information to your question. Still Missing is how your Pojo implementation looks like. Which annotations did you use? Furthermore you should update your example in regards to my latest comments.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You cannot Update `Frozen` types at all. You can only insert them.</del>

<del>A way to work around this, would be to get the current value first, assign it to a new Arraylist, and do an **insert** with the same entity but the new list.</del>

<del>See https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html</del>

**Update 1**

You should annotate your Pojo field with `@FrozenValue`otherwise the mapper doesn't know what to do.

See http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/object_mapper/creating/#mapping-collections

**Update 2**

You should also annotate your type POJOS with `@UDT(name="UserAssignment")`.

Comment: that's what I am doing - I am setting new arraylists

Comment: Yeah but you do `QueryBuilder.update`. This should be `QueryBuilder.insert` I think.

Comment: frozen means that I can't insert/delete new value in the list itself, but complete reinsert/reassign of the list should work. And with QueryBuilder, as you can see, it throws mapping exception.

Comment: if I am not mistaken, update is the same insert except it should crash if record is not found by Primary Key (however not 100% sure.)

Comment: You didn't use @FrozenValue?

Comment: I think this annotation is from 2.1 driver version. I use 3.2.0 so I don't have it :/

Comment: According to http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/object_mapper/creating/ you should at least use `@Frozen`?

Comment: as mentioned above, driver version 3.2.0 doesn't have these annotations.

Comment: See https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.2.x/driver-mapping/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/Frozen.java and https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.2.x/driver-mapping/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/annotations/FrozenValue.java both are still there. Also the Error message clearly states that you have a mapping issue there.

Comment: yeah, I didn't have cassandra-driver-mapping in my pom.xml. Added frozen annotation and still the same issue.

Comment: also read this from the doc above `Currently this is only for informational purposes (the mapper won’t check that the declarations match the rules in Cassandra)`